# PDF::FromHTML creates empty PDF

Tags: html, perl, pdf

I'm using `Perl`s `PDF::FromHTML` to create a PDF-file. My code looks like this:

```
open HTML, ">", "file.html";
...
close HTML;
chmod(0777, "file.html");

my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new(encoding => 'utf-8');
$pdf->load_file("file.html") or die $!;

$pdf->convert(
        Font => 'Arial',
        LineHeight => 10,
        Landscape => 1
);

$pdf->write_file("file.pdf") or die $!;
```

Since I had difficulties creating an actual PDF-file at the beginning, I'm now exactly following the synopsis on cpan, which is

```
my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' );

# Loading from a file:
$pdf->load_file('source.html');

# Perform the actual conversion:
$pdf->convert(
    # With PDF::API2, font names such as 'traditional' also works
    Font        => 'font.ttf',
    LineHeight  => 10,
    Landscape   => 1,
);
# Write to a file:
$pdf->write_file('target.pdf');
```

However this creates a PDF-file at the right location, but it only consists of a white page. The HTML-file is complete and looks like it should look. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a valid font. The second example has a non valid fontname.

If you installed PDF::API2 you could try to use: 'Helvetica' as fontname.

Please check you HTML file, it should be quite simple (no CSS or javascript).

Regards,

Comment: `Arial` seems to be a valid font, since with invalid fonts the script will die with an error `requested font 'calibri' not installed`. The HTML-File is very simple, just a small table with some links and a link to a `css`-file inside the head.

Comment: Did you tried to use the html2pdf.pl http://search.cpan.org/~audreyt/PDF-FromHTML-0.31/script/html2pdf.pl ?

Comment: No, i haven't, and I don't think it's useful, since the code in the script is basically the same, as my code.