# PDF::FromHTML - Corrupt file and no output

Tags: perl, pdf, cpan

Similar to this post [PDF::FromHTML creates empty PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546082/pdffromhtml-creates-empty-pdf)

I have the following code

```
    $textblob='<html><head></head><body><p>HelloWorld</p></body></html>';

    my $output;
    if(defined($query->param('PDF'))){
        my $pdf = PDF::FromHTML->new( encoding => 'utf-8' );
        $pdf->load_file(\$textblob);
        $pdf->convert(
            # With PDF::API2, font names such as 'traditional' also works
             Font        => 'Arial',
             LineHeight  => 10,
             Landscape   => 1,
        );
        $pdf->write_file(\$output);
        print $output;
    }
```

In Firefox this simply gives me an empty PDF page, when I save the page and view it in Acrobat it reports the file is corrupt/damaged and cannot be repaired.  TIA.

Comment: It works fine here: Ubuntu 19.04, perl version 5.28.1, pdf-viewer: evince. What OS are you on?

Comment: Remote shared server I honestly don't know.  I'm wondering if it's a headers problem.

Comment: Got it nm I had an un-necessary 'use binmode utf-8 STDOUT' at the top of page... duh

Answer (score 1):

My error was elsewhere in the script thanks for looking/commenting (note do not :

binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';

if you want to use this module obvs).

Of course the Anchors don't work/appear now for some unknown reason :-(